# Shipping datasets in postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, continuous-delivery

I was thinking about the best way to ship datasets in postgresql (or any) relational databases. For most of our use cases, we've put parquet files in timestampted folders, and had clients point to the most recent, validated dataset. If we couldn't change the client, then we'd have a "latest" folder that we'd put validated data into. What would be the best way of doing that with database tables? Generating the data and writing it to tables is a time consuming operation. We could take the database down, write to it, and then bring it back up, but that would take some downtime. Ideally, I'm looking for a way to write to the db in the background, validate the data, and then "flip" to make the new data "live". Are there easy ways of doing this? I guess I could have two databases in green / blue deployments and then have the client update, but was wondering if there's a way to do this without changing the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the size of your dataset there are several ways I would consider.

- The easiest one would be SQL script with data, e.g. `INSERT` or `COPY`.
- CSV file is fine and allows execute [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-copy.html) to fetch it.
- [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-pgdump.html) binary output file (or folder) is another choice and should be restored by [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-pgrestore.html)
- You may store your dataset in the file format you prefer and use [`file_fdw`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/file-fdw.html) foreign data wrapper to access it.

As you can see there a lot of options. So we need some details, I believe.

Comment: So the issue isn't inserting the data. It's more how to do it in the background and switch to the new dataset without updating the client (and not having downtime). If we do accept downtime, I can just truncate tables, insert and resume as normal.

Comment: Since DDL is fully transactional in Postgres you can insert data to a temporary table and then just switch with a real one.

Comment: That sounds interesting. How would the switch work?

Comment: worth noting, the dataset would involve multiple tables, but I expect that wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Something like this in my mind:
``` sql 
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE temp ...;
INSERT INTO temp ...;
DROP TABLE real_one;
ALTER TABLE temp RENAME real_one;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: That worked. Before loading new data, I create a table, insert, rename the old table to an archive one, then rename the new table to old. Had to deal with permissions, and only table owners can rename tables.